# File size limit and/or update count limit

Tags: sharepoint-designer, limitations

Is there a limit to the size of a file or the number of times file can be updated in SharePoint?

Recently had a file that could not be updated and was troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum file size **limit** is 2 GB. This can't be changed.

But SP web applications have much lower **configurable limitation** out of box, these are set in CA.

Default values are:

- For SharePoint 2013: default max file size is [250 MB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- For SharePoint 2007/2010: default max file size is [50 MB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a limitation on the number of times you can update a file in SharePoint. If you closely look into below article link you can see the Major Versions and Minor versions limit shown.

[SharePoint 2013 List & Library Limitations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary)

[SharePoint 2010 List & Library Limitations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#ListLibrary)

Regarding maximum file size upload, @Aziz has already informed you in his answer about the file size limitations. The above two articles also states the file size limitation. Check for File Size in the table.